# Canon Printer is producing garbage characters

Tags: network, printing, scanning

I have a Canon MF-4800 printer/scanner. It's been working fine up to last week. Now as you can see from the screen shots, it is mangling characters when printing. It scans ok, and prints test prints ok - also shown in another screenshot.

The machine is connected to my local network and is used by three Macs computers running slightly different versions of High Sierra.

I've tried:

Cleaning the printer,

Reconnecting the printer to my network,

Downloading new drivers

Any ideas would be welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you checked the ink level?

Comment: Yep, the printer software and the Apple Canon utility both indicate the ink is good. Also, it is printing ok when I simply copy an existing page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there has been a change in Apple's handling of printers -- at least mine.

When I print using the latest beta, the characters are malformed. When I print using 10.13.2, the printing is perfect.